# jQuery document.ready with ajax $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, .post

So I have a function that uses jQuery's $.post mechanism to fill in a div with contents from another page. I want to fire this method in the very beginning to show the content in the div right away. To do this I call the method in the document.ready script.

This is how the code looks:

```
    function OnloadFunction()
{
    alert("HELP!");
    var url = "<?php echo $this->url('public', array('id'=>'ajax')); ?>";
     $.post(url, {contentVar:cv}, function(data){
          $("#shoppingCart").load(data).show();
     });
}

//when document loads, do the following
$(document).ready(function(){
     OnloadFunction();
})
```

When I load the page, the alert saying "HELP!" shows up, but the $.post function is not making any difference and the div is not filled with the contents from the url.

P.S This shouldn't make a difference but I am using ZF2 (hence the url('public', array('id'=>'ajax')); ?>)

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

Comment: What URL does the ajax post to? Is the post a success or a 404? What is `cv`? What does debugging in the callback show for `data`? Is there an element on your page with id `shoppingCart`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead of [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/), assuming data is html content

```
 $("#shoppingCart").html(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like a charm! I would up-vote you but I don't have enough reputation points yet! Thanks again :)

Comment: @Steve-o-graph, great thanks for consideration and really glad to help fellow developer

Answer (score 2):

The `load` function takes a URL as an argument, makes an XHR request for it, and then populates the element with the response.

Presumably `data` is not a URL.